# How to fix push notification grey circle error?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I create launcher icon for iOS and Android with `flutter_launcher_icons`.

I also use `firebase_messaging` for push notification.

On iOS there is no issue: it show correct app icon on left of notification text.

But on Android the push notification icon is not show correct on left of text. It only show [gray circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEBFD.png) (no outline). I use adaptive icon for Android. It is not transparency issue.

Why there is difference? How I can fix?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use a transparent with white/black background icon for notification as a small icon.
you cannot use the color icon as a notification small icon, it will just display the shape of your icon that you used.

you can use your color icon as a notification large icon.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Even with adaptive icon? I use adaptive icon so I give background and foreground. Foreground have icon shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can use color icons for push notifications. you are not bound to use black & white icons only.

But you must you solid shapes only but transparent background of logo.